# How do I determine plate thickness and anchor size for a 10-ton span supported by synthetic rope?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering

I am supporting 25,448 pounds over a series of cables, spaced 20' apart, over a span of approximately 424', left to right.  The load is mostly in an area of the middle 10' of the span.  I am using synthetic rope/cable with 68,500# capacity.

I want to design a plate to secure the cable on both sides.  The plate will be attached to a curbing that is concrete roughly 24" thick.  How can I determine how thick my plate should be and what anchors I should use? I am planning to use 24" x 24" plates with an anchor in each corner.

Comment: Not a structural specialist by any means, but it seems to me that it might be useful to know the plate material, precise anchor placement, and method of fastening the plate to the curbing and/or anchors to plate. I assume the rope is [something like this](http://www.thomasnet.com/productsearch/item/1116733-14772-1150-2858/washington-chain-supply-inc-wcs/plasma60sup6217460-sup62-12-strand-synthetic-rope/)?

Comment: Please provide a sketch. There are various ways that you could be doing this. The configuration of the ropes could make a difference.

Comment: Given the magnitude of the loads involved this sounds like a situation where you need specialist professional advice.